# Keep getting corrupted .pdfs from request.get()

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm going to this state site and attempting to get the pdfs they have there with layoff info. When I run my code, I get no errors. However, the .pdfs keep coming back messed up--Adobe cannot open them.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import Session
import re
import urllib.request
import requests
import time

session = Session()

session.headers.update({
    "user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36"
})

init_session = session.get(url="https://mn.gov/deed/programs-services/dislocated-worker/reports/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(init_session.content, "html.parser")

MN_1 = soup.find_all('a', {'href': re.compile(r'/deed/assets/mass-layoff.*')})
MN_1 = [str(a) for a in MN_1]
MN_1 = [a for a in MN_1 if "2020" in a]
MN_1 = [re.search("/deed.*pdf", a).group(0) for a in MN_1]

url_head = 'https://mn.gov'

# looping through list of urls to get all 2020 Minnesota WARN reports
# There's a problem here; all of the returned .pdfs are corrupted; I added the time.sleep() thinking
# maybe python just needed more time to render them or something; still get bad .pdfs
for url in range(len(MN_1)):
    time.sleep(5)
    url_u =  url_head+MN_1[url]

    filename = 'Minnessota_WARN'+str(url)+'.pdf'
    stuff = requests.get(url_u)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(stuff.content)
```

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad, so can’t verify, but maybe try the pattern

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as fd:
for chunk in stuff.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
    fd.write(chunk)
```

And see if that helps?

Comment: Nor does the mn.gov site at the moment, unless it's got some form of geo-limiting active...